# Problem with Google API - Uncaught Error: Class "Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser

Tags: php, api, ads, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I got this Fatal Error/Uncaught Error while linking with the Google Ads API.
I've used the Github code and downloaded library from composer

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser" not found in googleAdword\examples\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns.php:44 Stack trace: #0 googleAdword\examples\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns.php(120): Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations\GetCampaigns::main() #1

Tried all these solutions:

1. reinstalling the lib, and not through zip downloading at first, but through git clone, and then install through composer etc.
2. In the sample code of GetAccountInformation, there is a CUSTOMER_ID field that is required before you execute the code.(Already set)

Comment: Did you run `composer install` to download the dependencies?

Comment: @Andy yes I downloaded it from github and used vandor from composer

Comment: The "examples" PSR4 is only autoloaded in dev... try running `composer dump-autoload --dev` to make sure that it is being dumped

Answer (score 0):

Downloading ZIP file from GitHub requires you to manually include all required classes. That's why you need autoloader. Good new is that Composer will automatically do that for you:

1. In your `composer.json` add line `"googleads/googleads-php-lib": "^57.0.0"` (correct package name and version if wrong) under `require`'d libraries list
2. Run `composer update` to download newly added library
3. In your code include composer's autoloader `require "/path/to/vendor/autoload.php";`

Comment: Yes! Did this, but still get the error.

Comment: I did everything to resolve above issue and make lots of R&D but issue not resolved. I checked google, many developers got this issue and are searching and commenting regarding this issue but I didn't see "issue resolved" Please provide me valid working code that can I used in my api request.

Comment: Since class namespace includes `Examples`, then try runing `composer install --dev`